# Scrape Odds Data from the Web [inside clickable elements] with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am looking to scrape the odds from this website:

https://www.sportsbet.com.au/betting/american-football

Specifically, I am going into each game market and I only want the following:

1. "Quartback Prop Markets"
2. "Rushing Prop Markets"

So if I go into one game (e.g. Detroit v Kansas):

https://www.sportsbet.com.au/betting/american-football/nfl/detroit-lions-at-kansas-city-chiefs-7354444

I scroll down to "Quartback Prop Markets", there are two markets, both need to be clicked to open:

[image]

When I scroll down to "Rushing Prop Markets", there are several markets that also need to be clicked to open:

[image]

I am trying to put all of this information into a csv file, like so:

```
  date        home_team     away_team      market          name             over   odds  under  odds
1 2023-09-08  Kasnsas City  Detroit Lions  Passing Yards   Patrick Mahomes  307.5  1.88  307.5  1.88
2 2023-09-08  Kasnsas City  Detroit Lions  Passing Yards   Jared Goff       256.5  1.88  256.5  1.88
3 2023-09-08  Kasnsas City  Detroit Lions  Rushing Yards   Isiah Pacheco    54.5   1.88  54.5   1.88
4 2023-09-08  Kasnsas City  Detroit Lions  Rushing Yards   Jahmyr Gibbs     39.5   1.88  39.5   1.88
5 2023-09-08  Kasnsas City  Detroit Lions  Rushing Yards   David Montgomery 49.5   1.88  49.5   1.88
```

My attempt so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from requests_html import HTMLSession

my_url = 'https://www.sportsbet.com.au/betting/american-football/nfl/detroit-lions-at-kansas-city-chiefs-7354444'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")

price_texts = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"priceText_f71sibe"})
filename = "odds.csv"
f = open(filename,"w")
headers = "odds team 1\n"

for price_texts in price_texts:
    odds = price_texts.span.text
    print(odds)
    f.write(" + odds ")
f.close()
```

This gives me some odds but they are incorrect. I can't work out how to go to the specific market and extract the data. It appears as though many of the divs have the same name. The above also doesn't give me the name of the player, just the odds.

**Edit:**

My second attempt using this:

```
price_texts = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"group_f1m0pc2a"})
```

Gives me all of the sub markets. But I cannot work out how to pull the odds from the relevant categories?

Also, this is just one game. I am trying to also go into each game on the NFL markets home page and extract the data for them also:

[image]